# Windows 10 Phone Calendar on Cross Platform Project

Tags: calendar, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to integrate device calendar into my Xamarin Forms application, however, in Windows 10 Mobile facing some serious issues!  On the platform specific project for UWP I call the following native API:

```
var store = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);
```

After calling the API, platform specific project throws this exception:

The message filter indicated that the application is busy.
A COM call (IID: {638BB2DB-451D-4661-B099-414F34FFB9F1}, method index: 6) to an ASTA (thread 9840) appears deadlocked and was timed out.

I guess it has something to do with multi-threading and application domain! considering that I have given the calendar permission to the app, anyone has faced similar error ever before?

### My Development Environment

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
- Version 15.1 (26403.7) Release
- VisualStudio.15.Release/15.1.0+26403.7
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02046
- Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.26403.07
- Xamarin   4.4.0.34 (3f99c5a)

Comment: As a quick test, can you call the API in the UI Thread and a Background Thread to see if one of them works. Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and Task.Run

Comment: Hi @AdamPedley I have called the Api in platform specific project immediately after LoadApplication(new App()) without Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread and it works fine! But when I tried to do the same thing using Xamarin Dependency Service and Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread the api returns null without any exception! I cannot clearly understand what's happening! Any idea?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue. But it is working pretty well in my project. Could show more detail about your interface implementation?

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT, I just quickly created a sample to repro the issue . . . uploaded the sample [here](https://github.com/PouyaJavadzadeh/Xamarin.App.Calendar). Please refer to MainPage.xaml.cs and App.xaml.cs under UWP project. One method is using Xamarin dependency service while the other method invokes the calendar on main UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your project and reproduced the issue. You could solve the issue by replacing `.Result` with `await` keyword.

> Although async programming is relatively straightforward, there are some details to keep in mind which can prevent unexpected behavior.
>
> **async methods need to have an await keyword in their body or they will never yield!**
>
> This is important to keep in mind. If await is not used in the body of an async method, the C# compiler will generate a warning, but the code will compile and run as if it were a normal method. Note that this would also be incredibly inefficient, as the state machine generated by the C# compiler for the async method would not be accomplishing anything.

For more detail please refer to [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/async).

It is not recommend doing more logic code in the property's get method. So you could get your `CalendarEvents` in `OnAppearing` method just like following code.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var events = await DependencyService.Get<ICalendar>(DependencyFetchTarget.GlobalInstance).GetEventsAsync();
}
```